# incrementing an entry in a 2d variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

What is the correct way to increment an entry in a 2d variable array?
It seems like Variant A (below) should have worked, but it fails with:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign_add'

Is there any way to fix this?
Variant B does work, but it performs more operations than necessary, and I'd prefer a proper assign_add as an atomic operation.
Somewhat strangely, Variant C below also works, and is *faster* than Variant B, although seemingly it does much more (unnecessary) work.

Variant A:

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
i = tf.Variable(5,tf.int32)
j = tf.Variable(3,tf.int32)
tbl = tf.Variable(np.zeros((10,10)),dtype = tf.float32)

p_op = tf.assign_add(tbl[i,j],1)
sess  = tf.Session(graph = graph)                    
tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)
res = sess.run(p_op)
```

Variant B:

```
p_op = tbl[i,j].assign(tbl[i,j]+1)
sess  = tf.Session(graph = graph)                    
tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)
res = sess.run(p_op)
```

Variant C:

```
p_op = tf.scatter_add(tbl, [i], [tf.one_hot(j,10)])
sess  = tf.Session(graph = graph)                    
tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)
res = sess.run(p_op)
```

Comment: [`tf.assgn_add()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign_add) is not a method of `Tensor`. you need to call `p_op = tf.assign_add(i, 1)`

Comment: Tried that. That would amount to tf.assign_add trying to execute tbl[i,j].assign_add as method, and give the same error. Still, edited the question.

Comment: Did you try just `tbl[i, j] += 1` and see what that resolves to? Is that the same thing as B?

Comment: @scnerd   Thats "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" at python interpreter level.. or "TypeError: 'Variable' object does not support item assignment" depending how you run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a graph, there isn't a good way to make `variable[indices] += value` return an operation which can then be executed in a session. And once the slice has taken place (as in `tf.assign_add(variable[indices], value)`), attributing the assignment back to the variable is rather difficult (not impossible in useful special cases; feel free to file a feature request, or even better put together a pull request).

The fastest way to increment a single element is likely to be `scatter_nd_add`, as in (modifying your example):

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  i = tf.Variable(5,tf.int32)
  j = tf.Variable(3,tf.int32)
  tbl = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((10,10)),dtype = tf.float32)

  assign_op = tf.scatter_nd_add(tbl, [[i, j]], [1])
  init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init_op)
    session.run(assign_op)
    print(tbl.eval())
```

This avoids a sequenced read->write as in your Variant B (i.e. is atomic), and avoids assigning a whole row as in Variant C.